# Fail2ban not recognising a custom jail

Tags: fail2ban

I have created a cusom jail in jail.local:

```
# detect password authentication failures
[AINA]
enabled  = true
filter   = pruebaAina
logpath  = /var/log/messages
findtime = 120
maxretry = 1
action_ = iptables-multiport
```

and created a filter:

```
[Definition]
failregex = WebFAX:\s\[<HOST>\]\sauthentication\sfailed

ignoreregex =
```

I have tried the filter-regex and it recogize the log error:

Jun 13 15:29:35 webfax WebFAX: [XX.XX.XX.XX] authentication failed for aina

The problem is that its not taking any acction. I have check the fail2ban log and there is no error and the jail is started.

I have tried the filter-regex and its working

Comment: Did you read the first line of the tag description (wiki)?

Comment: I can not understard what do you mean by tag description